# Changing language with React Hooks and Contex API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, react-context

I'm creating a page and it will be avaliable to use in 3 languages. I created 3 files that contain data neccesary to change displayed text. The concept is to check users browser language and display the language accordingly (it works ok) but also to give user option to change language of the page by buttons (it doesn't work). I used Context API to pass language and function to change language to other components - passing language worked but passing function didn't.  The problem is that the page doesn't respond when I click on the buttons when it passed like this:

```
changeToPl: changeToPl,
```

this way was used in article : https://medium.com/swlh/react-context-api-hooks-and-functional-state-7c9005b43432

but if I do it like this:

```
changeToPl: changeToPl(),
```

I have too many renders. Below App component that contain context and language logic:

```html
const LanguageContext = React.createContext({
    // language: '',
    // changeLanguage: () => {},
  }
);

const App = () => {

  let detectedLanguage = '';

  if (navigator.language.includes('pl')) {
    detectedLanguage = pl;
  } else if (navigator.language.includes('de')) {
    detectedLanguage = de;
  } else {
    detectedLanguage = en;
  }

  const [userLanguage, setUserLanguage] = useState(detectedLanguage);

  /*const chooseLanguage = (lang) => {
    // setUserLanguage(en);
    localStorage.setItem('lang', 'eeen');
    console.log(lang);
  }*/
  
  const changeToPl = () => {
    setUserLanguage(pl);
    console.log('pl');
  }

  const changeToEn = () => {
    setUserLanguage(en);
    console.log('en');
  }

  const changeToDe = () => {
    setUserLanguage(de);
    console.log('de');
  }

  // let chosenLanguage = userLanguage;

  const usedLanguage = userLanguage || detectedLanguage;


  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider 
      value={{
        language: usedLanguage,
        changeToPl: changeToPl,
        changeToEn: changeToEn,
        changeToDe: changeToDe,
      }}
    >
      <GlobalStyle />
      <CookieBanner />
      <PopUp />
      <Navbar />
      {/* <Sidebar /> */}
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} /> 
        <Route exact path='/artworks/:slug' component={Artwork} />
        <Route exact path='/exhibitions' component={ExhibitionList} />
        <Route exact path='/biography' component={Biography} />
        <Route exact path='/contact' component={Contact} />
        <Route component={Error} />
      </Switch>
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  );
}


export {App, LanguageContext};
```

and Sidebar component that contains buttons used to changing language:

```html
export const Sidebar = ({position, hideSidebar}) => {

  const usedLanguage = useContext(LanguageContext);

  return (
    <>
      <Route exact path='/artworks/:slug'> {/* DISPLAYED ONLY IN ARTWORK COMPONENT */}
        <Link to='/'>
          <BackButton>
            {usedLanguage.language.menu.backToMainPage}
          </BackButton>
        </Link>
      </Route>
      <Sidenav style={{right: position}}>
        <Link to='/' onClick={hideSidebar}>
          <Button text={usedLanguage.language.menu.artworksMenuButton} color={variables.DIMGRAY}/>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/exhibitions' onClick={hideSidebar}>
          <Button text={usedLanguage.language.menu.exhibitionsMenuButton} color={variables.DIMGRAY}/>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/biography' onClick={hideSidebar}>
          <Button text={usedLanguage.language.menu.biographyMenuButton} color={variables.DIMGRAY}/>
        </Link>
        <Link to='/contact' onClick={hideSidebar}>
          <Button text={usedLanguage.language.menu.contactMenuButton} color={variables.DIMGRAY}/>
        </Link>
        <LanguageButtonsWrapper>
      <Button text='pl' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={LanguageContext.changeToPl} />
      <Button text='en' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={LanguageContext.changeToEn} />
      <Button text='de' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={LanguageContext.changeToDe} />
    </LanguageButtonsWrapper>
        <SocialButtons>
          <SocialButtonIcon href='https://www.facebook.com/StructuralistArt/'>
            <AiFillFacebook />
          </SocialButtonIcon>
          <SocialButtonIcon href='https://www.instagram.com/structuralist_art/'>
            <AiFillInstagram />
          </SocialButtonIcon>
          <SocialButtonIcon href='https://www.behance.net/michalkrol263a63?fbclid=IwAR1LWaRyvVuh9UuM3MHByTYgqDOKG8Qo7h6mQq7tTM3ezJXU-HQ4Wtq09i8'>
            <AiFillBehanceSquare />
          </SocialButtonIcon>
        </SocialButtons>
      </Sidenav>
    </>
  )
}
```

I know that the function used to changing language could be more generic (3 in 1), context data could be in seperate file and that I have to use localStorage but for now I want to deal with described problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've figured it out. The problem was the structure of my App and btw. the thing I previously asked about :) Since I wanted to build reusable button, it looked like this:

```html
export const Button = ({text, color, clickHandler}) => {

  return (
    <AppButton onClick={clickHandler} style={{color: color}}>
      {text}
    </AppButton>
  );
};
```

and because of that I needed to pass changeToPl/changeToEn/changeToDe functions like this:

```
<Button text='pl' color={variables.DIMGRAY} clickHandler={usedLanguage.changeToPl} />
```

not like this:

```
<Button text='pl' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={usedLanguage.changeToPl} />
```

Comment: This is why naming "things" correctly/accurately is important. I suggest renaming `clickHandler` to `onClick` since that is what just about anyone using a "button" component would expect it to be, just from it being a simple "button" context.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your buttons should use the functions the context is providing, i.e. `usedLanguage.changeToPl` instead of `LanguageContext.changeToPl`:

```
const usedLanguage = useContext(LanguageContext);

...

<Button text='pl' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={usedLanguage.changeToPl} />
<Button text='en' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={usedLanguage.changeToEn} />
<Button text='de' color={variables.DIMGRAY} onClick={usedLanguage.changeToDe} />
```

You should also ensure the initial context value matches the shape that is actually used by components.

```
const LanguageContext = React.createContext({
  language: '',
  changeToPl: () => {},
  changeToEn: () => {},
  changeToDe: () => {}
});
```

Comment: The same, I tried to console.log() text and still no answer after clicking.

Comment: @Paweł Are you referring to the console logs (`console.log('pl');`) after the state update? Can you provide a running codesandbox that reproduces this issue we can live debug in?

Comment: I recreated simplified version in sandbox and it works fine - somehow it doesn't translate well to my project. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-pine-68sd6?file=/src/Navbar.js